Qiskit implementation of Oracle for Grover's Algorithm is Incorrect?
def oracle(qc, binary_strings):
    for string in binary_strings:
        if string[-1] == '1':
            for i, bit in enumerate(string[:-1]):
                qc.x(i)
                qc.z(i)
                if bit == '0':
                    qc.x(i)

Working on an oracle that flips the amplitude of an entire binary string if last bit = '1'.
This code should theoretically work (imo). Can someone explain if my code here is correct or incorrect? If it is incorrect is it due to the order of x and z gates? Thanks!

I’m voting to close this question because this question is asking about ChatGPT's interpretation of a snippet of code but it's not clear if the OP is asking if ChatGPT's interpretation is correct, or if the code is correct and ChatGPT is wrong, or what in particular is problematic with the snippet of code.

Thank you for your response @MarkSpinelli. I edited and cleared up some confusion in the question.

What you want is a python function that takes as an input an arbitrary list of elements, and generates an oracle that inverts the phase of only the elements in that list for which the least-significant qubit is $1$:
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZGate

def oracle(qc, binary_strings):
    n = len(binary_strings[0])
        
    for string in binary_strings:
        reverse_string = string[::-1]
        if reverse_string[0] == '1':
            MCZGate = ZGate().control(n-1, ctrl_state=reverse_string[1:])
            qc.append(MCZGate,range(n-1,-1,-1))

As an example, take the following list, for which only the first (001) and third (101) elements should be marked:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator

binary_strings = ['001','010','101','110']

qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
oracle(qc, binary_strings)
Operator(qc)

This code generates the following output, which as expected, is a unitary that flips the phase of states $|001\rangle$ and $|101\rangle$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am trying to invert the phase of the entire string when the LSB = '1'. Note that my qubits are all starting in a 0 phase which is why I apply the first X gate.

The way to posed the question implies that what you want to invert the phase of any state for which the least significant qubit is $1$. If this is not what you want, please clarify exactly what is it that you are trying to accomplish and I will edit my answer.

Sorry for the confusion. Say for example the binary string is 010011. I want this entire string to be marked using the oracle because the last bit = 1, indicating the solution. Does this help clarify?

It sounds like what you need is not an oracle that marks any element for which its LSB is $1$, but rather a python function that implements an oracle that marks an element iff its LSB is $1$, is that correct? If so, please edit your question to reflect that. Also, what is this function supposed to do if the LSB is $0$? not create the oracle?

I have an array of bits named binary_strings in which at least one row has an LSB = 1. There are about 5000 rows so I am using an oracle to mark the first solution state or solution string. What is the difference between writing an oracle or using a python function to call an oracle?

There is a big difference. An oracle that "that flips the amplitude of an entire binary string if last bit = '1' " (as you posted) is basically a unitary that inverts the phase of any input state for which the LSB is $1$. What you want is a python function that generates a oracle that flips the phase of states given some condition, but only for an arbitrary list of selected elements. This means the generated oracle changes if the provided list changes. I know how to answer your question, but please modify it so it is clear what is it that your asking. Also, remove any mentions of ChatGPT.

I've modified my answer to match what you're looking for.

Thank you for your answer. I have two theoretical questions though. 1: Wouldn't applying the MCZ gate to the target qubit only flip the phase of the 1 at the end of the binary string? 2: The first 2 qubits have at least 1 zero state and wouldn't that cause the MCZ gate to fail as these control qubits are not in the 1 state


No. It flips the phase of the full state that activates the gate.
That is what the parameter ctrl_state inside the control method is for. You pass a string that determines how the control is activated. For example, if ctrl_state='101', the control will be active for states where  = the control qubits are $|101\rangle$.


That makes sense. Thank you for all your help @diemilio.
